# Reading black pixels from an image

Tags: c#, colors, rgb

I have a 125*25 black and white .png picture. I want to read black pixels. For a led display. How can I do? In c#.

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.Height ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.Width  ; j++)
    {
        Color c = image.GetPixel(j, i);      //
        x = c.R ;
```

I can read red pixels but i want only black pixels.

Comment: How about x = (c.R < THRESHOLD && c.B < THRESHOLD && c.G < THRESHOLD); where THRESHOLD is the amount of that component within your 'black' tolerance.

Comment: Totally black pixels are c.R = 0, c.G = 0, c.B = 0

Comment: Yes, if your threshold is true black.... If your image isn't guaranteed to be monochrome, deciding what is 'black enough' to represent on a monochrome display is more threshold oriented...

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a number of ways you can achieve this:

- The way you yourself used, checking if the individual RGB values equal those of black:

  ```
  if (c.R == 0 && c.G == 0 && c.B == 0)
  ```
- Checking if the brightness is zero:

  ```
  if (c.GetBrightness() == 0)
  ```
- Or checking if a color equals another color:

  ```
  if (c.Equals(Color.Black))
  ```

And probably some more.

However if you use images, the colors are not guaranteed to be exactly black, especially if you use a photo or compressed image. You can work around this using a threshold, which you will have to (empirically) determine. A way of implementing such a threshold:

```
if (c.R < 30 && c.G < 30 && c.B < 30)
```

or like

```
if (c.GetBrightness() < 0.2)
```